# Drawable resources not changed after Locale changes & Activity restart

Tags: android

I change languages in my app using this code:

```
  protected void changeAppLangForUser(String lang) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(lang);
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

then restart Activity:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SplashScreenActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   getActivity().startActivity(intent);
   getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Strings are changed as expected but not icons stored in mipmap folders as following:[image]

It seems quite strange, but if I definitely close the app and then press on launch icon to start it again, it shows icons for expected language. Do I miss something or that's an expected behavior?

Comment: Try calling recreate() method instead of starting activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have `selector` resources in your `drawable` folder, that uses `mipmap` icons. If so, try to create folder `drawable-ru` and just copy paste them to this new directory. I had this issue before ;)